# How to use Nested map() functions while fetching data from Firebase Firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am learning React and I have some **menu** and **sub_menu** items, I made two different collections on the Firestore and I am fetching data from them. I wanted to show the menu and according to their parent id their submenu.

I used JavaScript map() inside the **map()** and my code works well but I wanted to know that is my way is right because I'm getting this warning in the console saying:

> Line 35:  Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function  array-callback-return

What am I doing wrong?

**project_action.jsx** (the action file using Redux's code)

```
// FETCHING HEADER MENU ITEMS
export const fetchMenuItems = () => {
    return (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase, getFirestore }) => {
        // MAKE ASYNC CALL
        const firestore = getFirestore();
        let mainData = [];
        let subMenuData = [];
        // GETTING MAIN MENUES
        firestore.collection('header_menu_items').orderBy('item_pos', 'asc').get().then(querySnapshot => {
            querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                mainData.push({
                    item_id: doc.id,
                    item_name: doc.data().item_name,
                    item_link: doc.data().item_link,
                    is_active: doc.data().is_active,
                    has_sub_menu: doc.data().has_sub_menu,
                    item_pos: doc.data().item_pos,
                    sub_menu: [],
                    // otherData: doc.data()
                });
            });

            // GETTING SUB MENUES
            firestore.collection('header_menu_categories').orderBy('item_name', 'asc').get().then(querySnapshot => {
                querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                    subMenuData.push({
                        item_id: doc.id,
                        parent_id: doc.data().parent_id,
                        item_name: doc.data().item_name,
                        is_active: doc.data().is_active
                    });
                });

                // BUILDING MENU
                mainData.map(item => {
                    if (item.has_sub_menu === true) {
                        return subMenuData.map(sub_item => {
                            if (item.item_id === sub_item.parent_id) {
                                item.sub_menu.push(sub_item);
                            }
                            return item;
                        })
                    }
                });


                dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_MENU_ITEM', data: mainData });
            });
        });
    }
};
```

**Printing data using it**

```
<ul>
    {
        props.mainMenu && props.mainMenu.map(item => {
            return (
                (item.is_active) &&
                <li key={item.item_id} className={item.has_sub_menu ? 'has-menu-items' : ''}>
                    <a href={item.item_link}>{item.item_name}</a>
                    {
                        (item.has_sub_menu) &&
                        <ul className="sub-menu">
                            {
                                item.sub_menu.map(sub_item => {
                                    return (
                                        <li key={sub_item.item_id}>
                                            <a href={sub_item.item_link}>{sub_item.item_name}</a>
                                        </li>
                                    )
                                })
                            }
                        </ul>
                    }
                </li>
            )
        })
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: Whats there on line number 35?

Comment: The var **mainData** is the mainMenu data Fetched from Firestore and **subMenuData** is the sub_menu table's data.

Comment: I used map on the **mainData** and checking if its has item which has has_sub_menu == true and after i'm comparing its id with subMenu's parent id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an eslint rule: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/array-callback-return

It enforces you to return something from any array filtering, mapping, and folding callback function

```
mainData.map(item => {
  if (item.has_sub_menu === true) {
    return subMenuData.map(sub_item => {
      if (item.item_id === sub_item.parent_id) {
        item.sub_menu.push(sub_item);
      }
      return item;
    })
  }
  // nothing returned here
});
```

An off topic note: Are you sure this function will really work?

I suspect that you wanted to do it something like this:

```
mainData.forEach(item => {
  if (item.has_sub_menu === true) {
    item.sub_menu = subMenuData.reduce((acc, sub_item) => {
      if (sub_item.parent_id === item.item_id) {
        acc.push(sub_item);
      }
      return acc;
    }, []);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanx, I used your function and its working very well. I was going to use for loop. but how can I forgot the reduce function. Thanx

Comment: I edited the answer. In this case you don't have to use Array.map() to create a new array which actually is not used anywhere. It's better for the efficiency to use Array.forEach() in this case.

Comment: Thanx so much for help.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the browser console or your system terminal? Looks more like the system terminal and the message says it all: `"Line 35: Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function array-callback-return"` You are most probably not returning a value. If you map over the array and in the callback you have an if -> what happens if the condition of the if is not satisfied? You won't enter it - so what are you returning when you don't go in the if statement - you guessed it - nothing. Depending on what you do, you can return false. Then filter all the elements and return just the one with a positive value.

Comment: Thanx, I figured at the end that I was not returning the value. and I did and my code works.